# How to delete margin between textInput and error massage

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I try to create app with fields validation and have trouble with margins.

Problem is that I can't make smaller margin between the `textInput` (Email) and the `uiOutput` (error message) smaller. I have already tried changing margin and padding of error message, but it doesn't help.

What I need to get in this simplify version:

1. There are two fields with normal distance (15 px) between them. And I need to keep the same distance when there is no error message.

[image]

2. When I click on Register button it validates and if username is empty the error is shown:

[image]

If I check code in my browser it shows margin-bottom 15 px:

[image]

Code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Error test"),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
        /* errors */
        .shiny-output-error-validation {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        font-weight: bold
        }
      "))),

  mainPanel(
    textInput("user_name", "Username (Email):", ),
    uiOutput("error_email"),
    textInput("bla", "Test:"),
        actionButton("register_button", "Register")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$register_button, {
    if (input$user_name != "") {
      shinyalert("Your registration was successfull")
    } else {
      output$error_email <- renderUI({

          validate(
          need(
            input$user_name != "",
            paste("Email Address: Please Input a valid E-mail address")
          )
        )
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: try using `body,html {border:0;margin:0;`, share the html code as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying negative margin-top on the element of the error message could be right solution to this issue. Please check the code below.

If the class in the element of error message is 'errormessage', following would be the css code.

```
.errormessage {
margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: I thought about the same. This should undoubtedly work.